# Spring boot application not able to detect table defined in sqlite db file

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application which uses SQLite db to perform CRUD operations. When I try to insert a row into the database, I always get this error. I want to be able to perform CRUD operations with the sqlite db. My stack trace is given below

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Chats)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:127) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:227) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:41) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:30) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:19) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:48) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:254) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:226) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1524) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
...
```

This is not correct because I am able to see the DDL of the table being created in SQLite client in the file.

[image: Chats DDL]

The SQLite db file is located at `src/main/resources/mydb.db`loction in the maven project. I tried the following configuration in my application properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:mydb.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.myproject.assignment.SqliteDialect
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The configuration for the dialect has been taken from the following SO posts

1. [spring boot: configure Sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890375/spring-boot-configure-sqlite-database)
2. [Spring boot and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232892/spring-boot-and-sqlite)
3. [resources in a Spring Boot application are missing from jar file when using Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197230/resources-in-a-spring-boot-application-are-missing-from-jar-file-when-using-spri)

Here is the method to insert code into the database.

```
public long insertChatRecord(final ChatRecord chatRecord) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOGGER.debug("Inserting chat record: " + chatRecord);
    }
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime expirationTime = dateTime.plusSeconds(
        chatRecord.getTimeout() != null ? chatRecord.getTimeout().intValue(): 60);
    final String timestamp = expirationTime.toString(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
    long chatId = SequenceGenerator.getInstance().next();
    chatRecord.setChatId(chatId);
    chatRecord.setExpirationTimestamp(expirationTime);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("INSERT INTO Chats(chat_id, username, chat_text, expiration_date) ");
    sb.append("VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    jdbcTemplate.update(sb.toString(), new PreparedStatementSetter() {

      @Override
      public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps)
          throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ps.setLong(1, chatRecord.getChatId());
        ps.setString(2,  chatRecord.getUsername());
        ps.setString(3,  chatRecord.getText());
        ps.setString(4, timestamp);
      }});
    return chatId;
  }
```

The exception is raised at this particular line.

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sb.toString(), new PreparedStatementSetter() {

      @Override
      public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps)
          throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        // Setting values for prepared statement.
      }});
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am running Spring Boot app in Eclipse. The main class is given below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public  class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

My pom.xml configuration as [suggested by plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) is given below.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: You should name your table as CHATS. It can't find your table because you using small letter

Comment: Hi, John, 
I can still reproduce the error even if I change the table name,

Comment: What about another table(s)? Can you see them or neither table can be accessed?

Comment: I can see them, but I can't access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the initialisation of database. section https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

I had to add a schema.sql that creates a table. The `schema.sql` was added to `src/main/resources` directory. Here is its content

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Chats;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Chats(username VARCHAR(20), chat_text VARCHAR(256), chat_id BIGINT, expiration_date TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(chat_id) )
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to put your db in resources `src/main/resources/mydb.db` but according to  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:mydb.db` spring is looking for db next to your jar/execution directory.

I think you should actually choose one

- Use `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite::resource:mydb.db` syntax to access **read-only DB** files contained in JAR archives [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027746/1032167)
- Put your db outside of a jar. In IDE it is probably near src directory:

  ```
  projectRoot/
     src/
     mydb.db
  ```

  And keep `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:mydb.db`.