# Spring-boot can't find sqlite driver

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite

I'm trying to integrate my spring boot app (web services) with Sqlite database, but I'm stucked at the beginning.
Due to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) I had specified connection url:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:test.db
```

And added dependency to apprpiate lib (with and without "scope runtime" result is the same):

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

(repositories...)
```

While I try to run my app I see information in console:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:
>
> Property: driverclassname
>
> Value: org.sqlite.JDBC
>
> Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
>
> Reason: Unable to set value for property driver-class-name
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

First thing what I had checked it's that lib with class org.sqlite.JDBC (sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar) is in my uber-jar (I generated it with mvn clean install with skip-tests flag) and it exists (it's packaged in my_app.jar\BOOT-INF\lib). Even when I'm starting my app from commandline I see same error (so it's not sts error).

Next, I thinked that maybe I have to specify driver class name manually, so i wrote:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
```

And then I see stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC
(...)
```

Next, I tried to add another starter:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

... but nothing was changed

I have no other idea how to deal with this problem. I had googled for configuring spring-boot and sqlite, but I didn't found anything helpful.

Please help, I'll be very thankfull for any clue :)

PS: my app was working properly on MySql database

PS2: I'm using newest version of hibernate and I don't have problem with sql dialect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot: configure Sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890375/spring-boot-configure-sqlite-database)

Comment: @sidgate , thanks for yuor response. I had seen earlier that question in provided link - my problem it's not duplicate it. I don't have problems with dialect